# Only The Last Cell Gets Highlighted No Matter What IndexPath is Selected in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is such a crazy thing happening and I just don't understand it.

I have a UICollectionView filled with images. I want to be able to select an image and draw a red border around it (or add an x, change the alpha, or do ANYTHING to it). But no matter what I do or where I put the code, ONLY the last image in the view gets the red border. Everything executes as expected after cell selection - (the correct image is removed (the one at the correct indexpath), the collectionview gets reloaded, and the document directory gets updated). Why can't I highlight the correct image?

I do have a TapGestureRecognizer to implement drawing the border if that makes a difference but it was doing the same thing when I called the code from a button press, in which case it was expected that ALL the cells would get a red border, but that didn't happen either. Only the last cell got the border???

To make it clear, say there are nine images in the collectionview. I can tap on index 0 but only index 8 ever gets the red border. Same thing if I tap on indexes 1 through even 8 itself, only index 8 ever gets the border.

Another thing I tried was to set an image of an x on every cell and hide it when presenting the collection view. I attempted to unhide it when an image was tapped at the selected index. Same thing happens. When a cell is tapped, the last cell gets the x and not the selected cell! What the heck?

All my NSLogs indicate that the correct indexpaths are being read and it is proven in the final outcome as everything gets updated but it is a poor user experience if the correct cell cannot be highlighted.

I would be most appreciative of any ideas on this ridiculousness.

**The cells are filled in a normal fashion:**

```
_cell.bookImageView.image = [_book.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**Here is the tap gesture in cellForItemAtIndexPath:**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *deleteImageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(deleteImageTapped:)];
deleteImageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
 _cell.bookImageView.tag = indexPath.row;
 [_cell.bookImageView addGestureRecognizer:deleteImageTap];
 _cell.bookImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

**This is all I'm attempting to do:**

```
_cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
_cell.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

**Or even this:**

```
_cell.alpha = 0.4;
```

**A few places I tried the code in:**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

//my tap gesture method
-(void)deleteImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture

//how I get the indexpath in my method
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:gesture.view.tag inSection:0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to "mention" my cell in didHighlightItemAtIndexPath and didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath. But for whatever reason, adding the changes to the cells never got called here.

I left the UITapGestureRecognizer in my cellForItemAtIndexPath and added the changes to the cell in the method called from my tap gesture.

**The basic set up is like this:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CollectionViewCell *cell;


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   _cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (!_cell.selected)
    {
        //this "turns off" the cell changes
        _cell.alpha = 1.0;
        _cell.deleteButton.alpha = 0.0;
        _cell.bookImageView.layer.borderColor = nil;
        _cell.bookImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    }

   UITapGestureRecognizer *deleteImageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(deleteImageTapped:)];
    deleteImageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    _cell.bookImageView.tag = indexPath.row;
    [_cell.bookImageView addGestureRecognizer:deleteImageTap];
    _cell.bookImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

   return _cell;
}


-(void)deleteImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    _cell.alpha = 0.4;
    _cell.deleteButton.alpha = 1.0;
    _cell.bookImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    _cell.bookImageView.layer.borderWidth = 5;


   //more code to delete image blah blah blah
}
```

**And then this is where I "mention" my cell**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)colView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)colView  didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I knows very well about your problem.
I suggest you to use a button in CellForRowAtIndexPath, instead of UiTapGesture.

First add button in your cell.

cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;

[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)yourButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender

{

if (sender.tag == 0)
{

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

}

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer but adding a button does not change the behavior. (I tried it out again). Also, CellForRowAtIndexPath is used in a UITableView. Did you mean cellForItemAtIndexPath? Even so, it is still not playing nice.